# The onclick method gets executed when I am declaring it

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am trying to declare an `onclick` method that will call a function that clears and rebuilds the display showing more detail on the item that was clicked.  The problem is the `onclick` method I am trying to assign gets executed when I assign it so all I see is the detail view of one of the items.

If you remove the `i.node.onclick` line you see 5 randomly placed items that you can hover over but not click on.

HTML

```
<html>  
   <head>  
      <title>Raphael Play</title>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Raphael.js"></script>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Test.js"></script>  
      <style type="text/css">  
        #map 
        {  
           width: 500px;  
           border: 1px solid #aaa;  
        }  
      </style>  
   </head>  
   <body>  
      <div id="map"></div>  
   </body>  
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var map;
var items = new Array();

window.onload = function() 
{  
   map = new Raphael(document.getElementById('map'), 500, 500);  

   for(cnt = 0; cnt < 5; cnt++)
   {
      var x = 5 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 490);
      var y = 5 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 490);

      items[cnt] = new Item(x, y);

      var i = map.circle(items[cnt].x, items[cnt].y, 8).attr({fill: "#000", stroke: "#f00", title: items[cnt].name}); 
      i.node.onclick = detailView(items[cnt]);
   }
} 

function Item(x, y)
{
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.name = "Item[" + x + "," + y + "]";
}

function detailView(dv)
{
   map.clear();

   map.circle(250, 250, 25).attr({fill: "#0f0", stroke: "#f00", title: dv.name});
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need a helper function:

```
  function detailViewer(item) {
    return function() { detailView(item); };
  }
```

Then you'd set the click handler like this:

```
  i.node.onclick = detailViewer(items[cnt]);
```

The helper function builds you a function that will, when it's called, call your "detailView()" function, passing in the item related to the node.  Your code as written simply *called* "detailView()" while performing the initialization, as you noticed.  The "onclick" attribute needs to be a function itself, which is what the helper function I proposed above will give you.

Comment: Another option is just declaring the anonymous function in the onclick: `i.node.onclick = function() { detailView(items[cnt]); }`

Comment: @Platinum Azure that would not work in this case, because the assignment is made in a loop!

Comment: Ah, I thought the assignment was to different nodes. I don't know anything about Raphael so I could be wrong. :-( (That said, it looks SUSPICIOUSLY like they would be equivalent, since your function returns what my anonymous function...)

Comment: @Platinum Azure the problem is that the variable "cnt" would be **shared** by all of the handlers - there's only one of them there in that function, so each closure would refer to the same value.  Thus when the handlers actually run, the value of "cnt" would be wrong!  This is a classic trap in JavaScript because only functions introduce a new scope.  You could do it "inline" by wrapping the function in **another** function, to make a copy of "cnt".

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand why my code didn't work.  Variable scope in JavaScript is tricky...

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `i.node.onclick` to a function.  You are setting it to `detailView(items[cnt])` which runs that function then sets `i.node.onclick` to the  return value (which is `undefined`).

You need to have `detailView` return a function.

```
function detailView(dv){
  return function(){
    map.clear();
    map.circle(250, 250, 25).attr({fill: "#0f0", stroke: "#f00", title: dv.name});
  };
}
```

Comment: What I like about this option is that I have one fewer function to maintain.