# How to prevent first onclick execution

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a javascript function that dynamically creates an Iframe with a button that if pressed can delete its iframe.

These are my javascript functions:

```
 function createIframe (iframeName, width, height) {
    var iframe;
    if (document.createElement && (iframe = document.createElement('iframe'))) {
        iframe.name = iframe.id = iframeName;
        iframe.width = width;
        iframe.height = height;
        var connectIP = document.getElementById("ip").value;
        var connectPORT = document.getElementById("port").value;
        iframe.src = "http://"+connectIP+":"+connectPORT;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        addElement(iframe.name);
    }
    return iframe;
}

function removeIframe(iframeName) {
    iframe = document.getElementById(iframeName);  
    if (iframe) { 
        var x=iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe) 
    }
}

function addElement(iframeName) {
    var butt = document.createElement('button');
    var butt_text = document.createTextNode('Remove');
    butt.appendChild(butt_text);
    butt.onclick = removeIframe(iframeName);
    document.body.appendChild(butt);
}
```

The problem is that, when the button is created, the onclick function is executed immediately and not only when the user presses it, so my new Iframe is immediately deleted and I cannot see it.

How can I solve this problem?

Moreover, is it possible to add the button not in the parent body but directly into the new created iframe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how u r adding the button  ??

Comment: @gsagrawal: *How, *are, *you, -?

Comment: Related (but slightly different context): [The onclick method gets executed when I am declaring it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111873/the-onclick-method-gets-executed-when-i-am-declaring-it) ... this problem comes up a lot here though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onclick has to be a function, replace following line

```
butt.onclick = removeIframe(iframeName);
```

with

```
butt.onclick = function() { removeIframe(iframeName); }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass function handler instead of function call result to `onclick` attribute.

You can do that using anonymously function:

```
butt.onclick = function() { removeIframe(iframeName); };
```